# How to associate static files with user in Express?

Tags: file, express, authentication, multer

I want to associate static files with particular users in express and place some kind of authentication so that a particular set of files can only be seen by the user they are associated with.

I am using multer to upload files.
My middleware serves all files requested.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

In my SQL database I'm storing the path of the image along with user_id. Now when a resource is requested I want to make sure whether the requesting user owns it otherwise reject the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a middleware function right before it and have that middleware check to see if the request is permitted - something like this.

```
app.use(checkUser, express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
```

`checkUser` would then need to be a middleware function that checks to see if the user is allowed to request this particular URL.  If not, then it returns an error and does NOT call `next()` so `express.static()` never sees the request.  If the user is allowed, then the middleware calls `next()` and `express.static()` will see if it can serve that URL.

Comment: Yes, but how do I identify the resource from the request?
The request url is something like /uploads/image.jpg
So if I get the "image.jpg" I can identify. However req.url just contains /favicon.ico
and req.originalUrl is undefined.

Comment: @SparshAgarwal - The middleware will be function checkUser(req, res, next) { ... } and req.url will contain the resource being requested.